# What is the difference between "./" and ". " to run script in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I submitting some computations to the cluster and found out, that if I run my shell script that has `qsub` in it with `.` (note the space after the dot) instead of `./` the scope of some variable change and I don't have problems with library access, as I have with `./`.

I know there have been questions about it before. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981933/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-commands-which-are-used-to-run-shell-sc) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331893/difference-between-different-ways-of-running-shell-script)

They discuss `sh` and `. ./` method, however, and don't touch on `.`

Is `.` the same thing as `. ./`?

Comment: `./` is just part of the path to the script, it has nothing to do with the way the script is run.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that the questions you linked to don't touch on your question. They both do.

Comment: `.` is a shell command (it's another name for `source`). `./` is just part of the filename. `. ./whatever` is always redundant, because `source` will look in the current directory anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
. cmd
```

vs

```
./cmd
```

are night and day different.

The first, is more like an "include", it executes the cmd within the context of the currently executing shell.

The second, is a path operation. `./cmd` is akin to `/usr/local/bin/cmd`. the `./` is a path specifier.

In this case, it is saying that you are running a `cmd` in the current directory, rather than searching the PATH env variable for `cmd`.

When the `cmd` is executed, it is forked and exec'd in to it's own process, unrelated to the current process. A completely different result from the first example.

Answer (score 1):

. is used to [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) a script. 
The script will be run in the current shell, and any variables it sets will be available afterwards.

./ is a way of saying the 'current directory', and is just a path reference.